# How to use heavier soldiers

Tags: science-based, biology, tactics

The other side of this question can be found here:
[How to use lighter soldiers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/161939/how-to-use-lighter-soldiers)

Imagine that tomorrow we invent a way to create soldiers that are almost the exact same in every single way as our current ones, just heavier. They have the same stamina, the same carrying capacity (not counting their weight*), they are the same size, aren't fatter or thinner and have the same amount of energy stored in their body.

Let's say for convenience sake that they can be anywhere between 20 kilos more weight up to three times the weight of an "ordinary" soldier. You can pick different weights for different tasks if you want if that gives them a better edge.

My question is how these soldiers would be used in our current day and age. What tasks would they be put to compared to their "normal" soldier counterparts.

I'm not interested in what they specifically won't be doing, I just want to know what tasks they would fulfill as infantry. Would always take point in an infantry formation or always hold back. Would they carry specific weapons to aid in their task etc.

*This means that if an 90 kilo normal soldier can carry 20 kilos of gear effectively, that the heavy soldier even if he weighs 200 kilos can still carry only 20 kilos of gear but still have just as much stamina etc.

Comment: I can't think of anything a soldier ever does where being heavier would be useful.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat Maybe smashing into opponents with brute force? But then again, an actual weapon would likely be better suited.

Comment: More expensive to ship, more expensive to equip (those boots are gonna wear out faster), no more effective with a gun. Doesn't seem like there are any upsides at all. In fact, if they have the same amount of energy in their body but weigh more, they'll get knackered faster and therefore be proportionally more useless than a normal soldier. There's nothing to like here.

Comment: @StarfishPrime "still have just as much stamina etc" is literally the last sentence. I didnt want to influence people but had come up with a range of options. The extra mass would mean less damage compared to any bodily-acceleration types of damage. I would assume things like battering down doors (a 90 kilo guy turns into a 270 kilo battering ram), hand-to-hand combat (or cegfault's pacification) and wielding weapons with great recoil would be their primary role as they suffer less from those effects.

Comment: @Demigan if they have the same amount of energy in them, they can't have the same stamina for greater mass, because everything they do clearly requires _more_ energy. Otherwise, what you have is a (fairly simple, low output) perpetual motion machine. Maybe the best job is to get them to jump up and down on a power generating mechanism.

Comment: And using a heavy soldier as a battering ram seem inappropriate when modern technology provides a wealth of tools that will do the job ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## Policing Occupied Territories

Something we don't talk about a lot - whenever a military captures a city, they in effect become a police force until the situation stabilizes.  That means resolving disputes between individuals, handling debts, etc.  There's a huge grey zone here as to what a military can/or should do, but a simple google or youtube search will give more than enough to make you laugh and cry.

Heavier soldiers make for one intimidating policing force.  The locals are *very unlikely* to take a swing at a man three or four times his weight.  Tackling him would prove... foolish.  If weapons are involved then yes, the military has their guns.  In occupied territories however, use of weapons is *strongly discouraged* for the simple reason it makes the locals *hate you*, which increases the chance of rebellions popping up.  You don't want to be fighting locals internally while a military is at the city gates.

So take your heavier solders and let them resolve the disputes and police occupied territories until the situation stabilizes.  They're better able to take a hit, more likely to not be injured, and can provide a sense of justice in the short-term.

Comment: The OP states "*...they are the same size, aren't fatter or thinner....*" How would the local know that the soldier is heavier? On the other hand, post-assault, completely agree that the heavier soldier would seem more able to take the hit.

Comment: @user535733 word spreads fast.  Also more mass = more sound when walking.  You're right it wouldn't be obvious at first.  But the *first guy* who tries it will find out quick, and then word will spread around the city *really fast*